# How to force a flinging action to always scroll the same distance no matter the velocity or the threshold of the fling?

Tags: android

The question title pretty much explains all I'm trying to achieve. I think I don't need to post any code, as the flinging code I'm using is well spread here on stackoverflow.

I'm using an `OverScroller.fling()` to effectively perform the flinging. According to the docs, the flinging distance is calculated according to the velocity provided by the flinging gesture.